# How to make table legs from wooden planks?

Tags: wooden-furniture, table, recycling

I'm making a coffee table out of old pallets. The top part is finished, all it needs now is legs. I want to use only parts from old pallets and I don't want it to become very heavy, so I was thinking of using 2 planks in a 90° angle on each corner of the table as legs. I have no experience in woodworking so I don't know if this is a good idea or how to do this...

1. Will 2 planks in a 90° angle be stable enough as a coffee table leg?
2. Should I mount the planks on each side of the corner of the table top
   or should I mount them under the table top and hold them in place
   with a frame?

It would be appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

90 degree planks will be plenty strong assuming they are not super narrow. Without knowing the details, it's not possible to suggest the best connection. You will want to connect to whatever member has the greatest vertical depth for maximum stability. Do everything possible to ensure the legs are rigidly attached. Nails or screws alone may not be enough. If possible, slightly rabbet the legs into something. The rabbet does not need to be very deep to help significantly. Of course, the fit needs to be fairly snug to be of benefit. Also glue the joints unless the need for disassembly is important. Common woodworker's glue is adequate.